# Version and snapshot release to releases, only version release is needed. Why two releases?

Tags: java, maven

I created org.ciwise group and ciwise artifact. Yesterday I deployed 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT to snapshot repo with "mvn package gpg:sign deploy". Everything is fine. I then manually changed the version to 1.2.0 and did same. Everything looked fine in Maven console output.

When I visit the releases repo, I now see 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT and 1.2.0

Can someone help me determine why the SNAPSHOT is in releases? I only expected the one latest version 1.2.0 because I changed the version in my POM.

Comment: Can you specify your "releases repo" - what sort of repo is it, and how is it configured? For example is it artifactory or are you referring to your local repo by any chance.

Comment: And can you show the `<distributionManagement>` from your pom (or any of the parent poms)

Comment: `SNAPSHOT` is in releases because probably it was allowed by the repository configuration. Moreover and just to clarify, releasing `1.2.0` would not automatically remote its `SNAPSHOT` from the repository anyway.

Comment: <distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>ossrh</id>
           <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
 </distributionManagement>

Comment: Also, I didn't check https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/ciwise/ciwise/ when I did the deploy with the version set as 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT. The ref docs said that if the version has -SNAPSHOT ... the deploy goes to the snapshot repo at Maven central. When I did the release I just did this 1) change version to 1.2.0 (removing -SNAPSHOT) and 2) mvn package gpg:sign deploy . I don't have any profiles or such. I'm new to all this so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.